Change WS Propertie in Discord JDA
In JavaScript with Discord.js, there was an option to customize the WebSocket properties by setting the ws property, like changing the browser to something like "Discord iOS." For example:
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
    ws: { properties: { $browser: "Discord iOS" }}
});

Is there a similar way to achieve this in Java using the JDA (Java Discord API)?
I have already tried modifying the WebSocket properties in Java using the JDA (Java Discord API) by working with the WebSocketFactory, but it didn't seem to change anything. Specifically, I attempted to customize the WebSocket properties, similar to how it's done in Discord.js, by setting something like the $browser property, but no effect was observed.

Not possible in JDA.
